# Summing a set of cells that appears after every x amount of rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I know there must be a simple way to do this, but I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

So I have `Sheet1` that has a some number values in `Column M`. I have a set of 10 cells that I want to sum up, starting from M2:M11. However, these set of 10 cells appear regularly after 60 blank rows. So, I would want to sum up M2:M11 and then M72:M81 etc.

These Summed values would appear in Column A row 2 in `Sheet2`, where I would want to use the Drag/drop down function to populate the cells with the Summed values.

I have the following formula so far, but how do I add in the "skip 60 rows after you sum the set of 10 cells" part for the drag-down function to work?

`=SUM(OFFSET(Sheet2!$M$2,(ROW()-2)*10,0,10,1))`

I have been trying to figure this out for a long time so any help would be immensely appreciated! Thanks so much in advance!!

Comment: Post a screen shot please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to modify your formula a bit:

```
=SUM(OFFSET($M$2,(ROWS($1:1)-1)*70,0,10))
```

As you "fill down", the rows argument will increment by 70 for each row you fill down.

Comment: This is perfect thanks so much! I figured it was an easy fix and now I feel so silly that I didn't think of this before.

Comment: @user623960 I can't tell you how many times I've labored over a problem, only to eventually find what seemed, in retrospect, to be a simple solution.