# Running total calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I wish to add the values of column B and display the result in column C.
I wish to vary the number of cells counted by reference to a separate user entered number (A1).
Example 1:

```
A1=12
C4=SUM(B4:B16)
C5=SUM(B5:B17)
```

or Example 2:

```
A1=2
C4=SUM(B4:B6)
C5=Sum(B5:B7)
```

Where (non syntax code following)

```
C4=SUM(B4:B'ROW(B4)+A1')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula :

`=SUM(OFFSET(B4,0,0,$A$1)`

Comment: Thank you Máté.

i found this link of assistance as-well.

https://superuser.com/questions/1107552/summing-a-set-of-cells-that-appears-after-every-x-amount-of-rows?rq=1